# Kubernetes pod stuck in "pending"

Tags: kubernetes

All of a sudden, i wanted to change my hostPath mount to a new glusterFS mount I've made. And when i delete the mount, the pods of these deployment keeps like this for always, i attach some outputs:

```
kubectl describe pod [podname]
-->
Name:           otpnxus-5b4b974b65-7s5sb
Namespace:      ouapi
Priority:       0
Node:           node2/
Labels:         app=otpnexus
                pod-template-hash=5b4b974b65
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/otpxus-5b4b974b65
Containers:
  otpnexus:
    Image:      dockerhub.privaterep.com
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      otp
    Args:
      --server
      --autoScan
      --insecure
      --verbose
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/otp/graphs from volum-otp (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-nm479 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  volum-otp:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/nexus/dades_otp/graphs/
    HostPathType:
  default-token-nm479:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-nm479
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  6m18s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned sapi/otpxus-5b4b974b65-7s5sb to node2
```

and logs are not available:

```
 kubectl logs otpnexus-5b4b974b65-7s5sb
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log otpxus-5b4b974b65-7s5sb)
```

What can i do?

Comment: Delete all related pv, pvcs and deployments, and then re-apply the correct pv,pvc with gluster configuration and then apply deployment

Comment: Also wait for sometime and then check the output of kubectl describe pod <podname> it will show you exact error. And possibly it's mounting error. re-applying correct configurations will surely help

Comment: What is your infrastructure?  Can you please add output from `kubectl version`?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to run you Image from Image: *in Docker*[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) directly. with the mentioned command and args, then you should be able to see some log lines.